# Одна или две "т"?

Tags: удвоенные-буквы

Твиттнуть статью или твитнуть?

Comment: Добрый день! Вот, что нашла! 

В вышедшем в 2012 году 4-м издании «Русского орфографического словаря» РАН зафиксировано: торрент и «Твиттер» (тем самым написание «Твиттер» подведено под общее правило написания условных наименований – в кавычках с прописной).

Но тогда в "твиттнуть" сохраниться двойная? Или нет? Есть ли такое правило?

Comment: Нет.
Твиттер - это нормально. Там и произносится двойная или что-то близкое. 
А вот твитнуть - это отдельная статья, уже производное.
Хотя я так и не понял, как твитнуть можно ***статью***.

Comment: В конце статьи стоит кнопка "Твиттера". Нажать на нее - твитнуть статью (запостить ссылку на нее в "Твиттере).

Comment: Ааа... Т.е. не статью "твитнуть", а ссылку на оную. В этом значении, может, оно и приемлемо как профжаргон... 

Но это не в смысле орфографии.

Answer (score 4):

От этого словечка у меня аж мурашки пошли... 
Но если отвлечься от подобных перлов, то общее правило таково, что при заимствованиях удвоенные согласные не сохраняются, если для иного нет фонетических оснований. 
В производных от заимствований это можно считать императивным требованием.
Так что я за "твитнуть". 
Но еще лучше - как-нибудь по-русски.
Не знаю как, ибо смысла не очень понимаю. Что это "твитнуть" может значить в отношении ***статьи***?

Comment: Согласен, что "твитнуть" звучит естественнее, чем "твиттнуть". Но не против, если некоторые будут писать "твиттнуть". А еще лучше заменить этот новояз на что-то другое типа "отметить статью в Твиттере"

Answer (score 0):

Вот уж точно, что аж мурашки от такого словесного монстра. Почему нельзя написать нормальным человеческим языком: "опубликовать статью в Твиттере" или "выложить статью"?

Comment: Они смысл другой вкладывают.
Это именно ссылка, не сама статья.
Аналога в обычной речи я не нахожу. 

Впрочем, это не меняет моего отношения к самому глаголу.

ЗЫ Самое близкое - "дать рекламу", "отрекламировать".

Comment: Ну, слово "твитнуть" тоже неплохое. Ведь действие новое, почему бы не дать ему новое название? Если говорить об "иностранщине" - так "реклама" слово тоже не русское, просто уже привычное.

Answer (score 0):

От существительного "твиттер" глагол по идее должен быть "твиттерить". Твитить явно разговорный вариант и удваивать согласные тут ни к чему.

Comment: Так "твиттер" само от "to tweet" - чирикать. Твиттер - воробышек.
И по-английски подобное действие наверняка тоже "to tweet".
Твитнуть - чирикнуть.
Кстати, может это и есть "хороший" вариант перевода?!

Comment: @behemothus, в русском языке у "твиттер" цельное заимствование, в "тетради" же мы при словообразовании "тетра" не выделяем.

Comment: Допустим.
А кто Вам сказал что "твит" 0 это выделение из твиттера?
Твит - это отдельное сообщение в твиттере.